# I want to add a prefix to my database Drupal8 how?

Tags: 8, database, configuration

[image]I want to add a prefix to my database Drupal8 how? I change the file  setting.php but it appears an error

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Changing the `$databases['default']['default']['prefix']` setting does not change your database. You'll have to either manually prefix your existing DB tables or run the installer again while placing the **d8_** prefix in the **Advanced Options > Table name prefix** field of the D8 installer.

Comment: ,I did not understand, how exactly?

Comment: Use your MySQL client to rename all the tables with d8_ in front of the name or run the Drupal installer again.

Comment: I added the prefix directly with phpMyadmin but still error occurs

Comment: My guess is it might be a cache issue, but without access to your environment, it will be all guesses.

Comment: This is the answer. You would have to reinstall and set the table prefix setting in the wizard, or rename all the tables to d8_ in database.